# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint Please Verify

Tags: sql-server

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__faredestin__svno__503BEA1C". The conflict occurred in database
>   "travelproject", table "dbo.bus", column 'svno'. The statement has
>   been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

svno column is used as FOREIGN KEY in table.you have to consider FOREIGN KEY hierarchy while insert/delete operation.And FOREIGN KEY must be unique value and record must be in main table for given FOREIGN KEY.

while Inserting in to table check what value goes in svno column and check whether their is record for given svno in table where svno is used as a PRIMERY KEY.